# How to change the lock screen type programmatically?

Tags: android, locking, swipe

I am working on an Android Application where I need to access the different lock screens(e.g.- pin lock,pattern lock etc.) and also able to change it using my application upon some event.

I have searched a lot over it but so far I am stuck. Please if anyone can help me out with this problem.
Thanks

Comment: So you want to change the "Screen lock" type?

Comment: @LegendaryGenius Yes, for e.g. from Pin Lock to Swipe Lock ;

Answer (score -1):

See if this page helps:[Android Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

You should be able to access the inner elements if you watch the logcat output keenly.
Still I am not sure whether you will be able to set a patter or PIN lock as the user needs to be involved in it.

But I guess you should be able to change the type from "slide lock" or "No lock" as just the elements needs to be selected.

Comment: Thanks... I will have to try it out but I have my apprehensions about it.